# How do I rescue Josie Thorpe?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

At the end of the first mission, you have to negotiate with the terrorist leader and try to convince him to let Josie Thorpe go. Unfortunately, I didn't say the right thing, and she didn't make it out alive.

How do I convince the terrorist to let her go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to do it by sympathizing/selecting empathy with him three times. Logic seems to piss him off, and humble doesn't do much.

However, after selecting empathy, he seemed to hesitate, agreed with what I said, and backed off a little bit.  So after seeing that reaction, I just stuck with it for the other 2 choices, and it worked.

Comment: Note that this will keep the terrorist alive, while other options will result in his death.  Though it will piss people off, keeping him alive seems to be the better choice (he comes back later on).

Answer (score 6):

After having done the "persuasion" minigame a few times by trial and error, you can see that there are multiple ways to get finished: the conversational tree weaves around the central "you win" thread. You can tell that you've "hit" the person you're talking to...They visibly react. And if they back off, or get calmer, you're on the right track.

On the other hand, they also visibly react in a negative way, and you need to watch for that too, because your screw ups (and your successes) will color the whole conversation. I had a lot more trouble with the later boss conversation (protip: Don't go in defensive. If you get in his face early, he will chew you up and spit you out), and I ended up running through it three times, and some of the "telling" shots showed up in winning *and* losing runs.

I think it must run on a "point" system, where you get points for choosing the right way, and lose points for choosing the wrong way, and if your point total is high enough, you win.

I can't remember the exact sequence I used to free Josie. I mucked around in the bottom 2 (not aggressive or humble, but logic and the other one) until he started trying to leave with her, and then I hit him with humble, and he let her go. I honestly thought several times I was screwing it up, but it worked out, and I got "silver tongue" credit for it.

I definitely think you need to not be too hard, or too soft on him early. I think that either one of those will drive him the wrong way. Sarif was similar. If you call him out early, he slaps you down, but if you never call him out, he doesn't give you anything...You've got to be cool and rational, and then WHAM! Nail him below the belt when the shot opens up.

Answer (score 3):

I did it by doing each of the three options Rational, Empathize and Humble in that order (I think those were the names).

Answer (score 3):

I got through with

1. Try to free Josie
2. Reason
3. Reason
4. Humble

So apparently there are several ways through. Which is to be expected: the DX3 developers have kept the DX1 ethos that there's never just one way to accomplish something.

Comment: That's what I did as well.

Comment: Confirming that Reason - Reason - Reason also works.

Answer (score 3):

One more answer: You can fight Zeke, and if you take him down fast enough Josie lives. In fact, if you take him down with the stun-gun (and also saved the earlier hostages) then the SWAT team really likes you.

Comment: +1: In my "guns blazing" playthrough, I didn't even talk to him - just chose to fight and shot him in the head immediately.  Job done.

Answer (score 2):

Just an additive note to the other answers- the social battles *are* semi-randomized. Specifically, I both succeeded *and* failed to convince Haas to let me into the Morgue with the two same attempts. I believe that some are guaranteed to succeed, some might, and some will definitely fail.

Comment: Actually, I think it's more likely that the character's ending "convinced" status (as measured by CASIE mods) translates to a % chance of convincing. I'm pretty sure the conversation responses are always the same.

Answer (score 1):

At first I tried doing the Empathize x3 but all that did was get her shot by the cops, so I went back and did empathize, reason, empathize and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I did Humble > Empathize > Reason (or Empathize > Humble > Reason, can't remember the exact order of the first two). It was "You said you're a vet" and then "coward hiding behind a skirt" and then "that's how well he knows you." Saved them both, got silver tongue achievement, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What i did in the situation was:

1. Try and let Josie go.
2. Reason.
3. Reason.
4. Reason.

And it worked and you get a acheivment for Silver Tounge

Answer (score 0):

This might come in handy...

https://deusex.fandom.com/wiki/Ezekiel_Sanders_Dialogue_Challenge

The short, easily-memorised version: Always go with Empathize for the first two choices/"rounds", then watch what Sanders says after your second answer.

If he starts saying "You know what", make your third choice Reason.
In all other cases, stick with Empathize.